# Disable javascript in Tor Browser Bundle 4.0.2

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, javascript, noscript

I can't find a way to disable JavaScript in Tor Browser Bundle version 4.
References on the net refer to previous versions.
Also can't find Noscript either.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of Tor Browser Bundle has the NoScript icon on the top left of the page:

[image: Screenshot with S!]

Just click on the `S` and the menu of NoScript will open. Here you can disable JavaScript or make other changes.

Comment: The NoScript icon is not there on my TOR 4.0.2

Comment: Can you make a screenshot and upload it to some image sharing site? Do you use Tor Browser Bundle?

Comment: I removed the TOR bundle and re-downloaded a new version 4.0.2
The Noscript icon has now appeared next to the 'onion'.
Thanks for your help.